# NulledPointer Exception on Changing from support-v4 to appcompat-v7

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

My app uses Theme.Holo.light using com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3. Now I changed my app theme to Theme.Appcompat and Changed the gradle dependencies too from "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3" to  "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3".
After these changes my app get crashed whenever I launch it.
and getting the log

> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object
>   reference
>               at com.viter.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)

My function is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Code for Tabs
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }


    // Navigation Drawer
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}
```

Please help me out resolving this.

Comment: @Dave S no. build success but app get crashed again.

Comment: Just something to keep in mind, `.setNavigationMode()` has become deprecated as of API Level 21.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` (and also extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`).

Comment: I tried but I'm unable to use getSupportActionBar(). as my class is "public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener"

Comment: @Vrangle Hmm, I think you should extend `ActionBarActivity` too.

Comment: Already I extended FragmentActivity. then how can I extened to ActionBarActivity again. Class cannot extened multiple classes.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`

Comment: @ianhanniballake tried. this time some thing un expected errors at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$TabListener
            at com.viter.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:123)

Answer (score 1):

With AppCompat v21 you can add a Toolbar and use that as the ActionBar. It isn't hard to do, and most of the code won't need to be changed. The main thing is to add the toolbar to the activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

And then use this to make your Actionbar

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

}

Depending on the rest of your code their might be a few other things to update. But this should get you most of the way. Further details here: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: Note: Toolbars are totally optional in AppCompat v21 - AppCompat will inflate a Toolbar for you (and return it via `getSupportActionBar()`).

Comment: @Alt-Cat I tried the way answered. but nothing much and a error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$TabListener
            at com.viter.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:123)

Comment: Try making the MainActivity extend ActionBarActivity if you haven't already. You may also need to remove some of the imports you are using in the class and adding them back for the v7 support library. I can't remember which one, but some v7 and v4 methods share the same name.

Comment: @Alt-Cat no more improvements. If you wish let me revert back all the changes and give you working app, you please change the theme and give me

Answer (score 0):

Check if your

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

is returning null for an actionBar.

You're probably calling the code in the wrong class.

Comment: no chance of returning null. by the way when I revert back to Theme.Holo.light and gradle dependecies to com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 it works as usual.